# ajax will_paginate drops the page to first when browser page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, will-paginate

I'm beginner in RoR and I have app in which I use ajax with will_paginate like in [#174 Pagination with AJAX - RailsCasts](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjftqKq4YLRAhWHjiwKHUXTDikQFggYMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Frailscasts.com%2Fepisodes%2F174-pagination-with-ajax&usg=AFQjCNGI7J-jAd9c4CleWagw36-rN3xS3A&bvm=bv.141536425,bs.1,d.bGg). All working fine, but I have issue such as after I select any will_paginate page and then refresh browser page will_paginate drops the page to '1'. I can't think that it is necessary to make that in case of refreshing of the browser page the will_paginate page still remained page selected early. Some my code:

_index_table.html.erb

```
<%= will_paginate @outdoor_advertisings, :param_name => 'order_page' %>
  <table class="index_table">
    ...
  </table>
<%= will_paginate @outdoor_advertisings, :param_name => 'order_page' %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="index_table">
  <%= render 'index_table' %>
</div>
```

index.js.erb

```
$("div#index_table").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("index_table")) %>");
$(".ajax-progress").hide();
```

controller action

```
class OutdoorAdvertisingsController < ApplicationController
  def index

    if !params[:order_page].present?
      params[:order_page] = '1'
    end

    @outdoor_advertisings = OutdoorAdvertising.where(active: true)
    .paginate(page: params[:order_page], per_page: 30)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
    end 

  end
end
```

outdoor_advertisings.js.coffee

```
$("body").on "click", "div#index_table .pagination a", ->
  $(".ajax-progress").show();
  $.getScript @href
  return false
```

server console log when index page open first time

```
Started GET "/outdoor_advertisings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-20 16:36:09 +0200
Processing by OutdoorAdvertisingsController#index as HTML
```

server console log when select page

```
Started GET "/outdoor_advertisings?&order_page=3&_=1482244577710" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-20 16:36:20 +0200
Processing by OutdoorAdvertisingsController#index as JS
Parameters: {"order_page"=>"3", "_"=>"1482244577710"}
```

server console log when browser page refresh after will_paginate page '3' select

```
Started GET "/outdoor_advertisings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-20 16:36:24 +0200
Processing by OutdoorAdvertisingsController#index as HTML
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using ajax to dynamically change the content of the DOM, when you refresh the page it starts back at the beginning before the content was dynamically changed. If you were using html and visited page 3 and then hit refresh, it would still be page 3.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guessed that the reason in AJAX use, but I can't invent how to make that AJAX continued to work and didn't change number of the page in case of refresh the browser page. You can prompt a trick? Thanks.